# Android: Setting a table row visible in the main java class

Tags: java, android

I have a Tab1 class and the main class.

**Tab1 class below** - sets the table row to invisible:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    View v;
    TableRow tr;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        tr = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.tb1_r1);
        tr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tr = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.tb1_r2);
        tr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tr = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.tb1_r3);
        tr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tr = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.tb1_r4);
        tr.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return v;
    }
}
```

In the main activity:

I have a popup window that contains a button and when it is pressed it will set one of the table rows to visible. Right now I am just trying to set the first table row visible.

```
public void BtnAddContact(View view) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "New Contact Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    popupWindow_addcontact.dismiss();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, null);

    TableRow tr = (TableRow)view1.findViewById(R.id.tb1_r1);

    tr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

It runs and no error message shows. The toast message appears but the table row does not become visible. Can you tell me why the table row is not becoming visible? It has to do with not accessing Tab 1 java class I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `BtnAddContact()` method:

Instead of inflating view and setting its visibility to visible - you need to find this view in your fragment and then set its visibility:

```
yourTab1Fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tb1_r1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or if you only have this 1 fragment then simply skip these 2 lines:

> ```
> LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, null);
> ```

and directly call:

```
  TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tb1_r1);
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to have the onCreateView() Method in my main java class. I am not sure how to find the view in my fragment.

Comment: @akalanta My suggestions are for `BtnAddContact` method. Remaining code is fine. Please see updated answer.

Comment: So what I did was:   Tab1 tb1 = new Tab1();                      tb1.getView().findViewById(R.id.tb1_r1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                               The error that I get is : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @akalanta Please check second approach mentioned.

Comment: I will be using Tab1 and Tab2 eventually. So will I be using the first method you mentioned

Comment: @akalanta But remember that in order to use view from fragment - you need to find this fragment in FragmentManager and then call method on it. If you just create new Tab - your activity will not know what it is and what to do with it. So first - create tab, then add it to activity and then if you want to make it visible or invisible - find it using Fragmentmanager and then use 1st approach I mentioned

Comment: Hi there again, I have a ViewPagerAdaptor.java file, Tab1.java and Tab2.java.In the main activity class I defined two fragments that are set to the tabs as shown below:           tab1 = adapter.getItem(0);                                                                                           tab1.getView().findViewById(R.id.tb1_r1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                        I still get Null pointer exception error. It is still unable to get it. Is it because I have a pop-window open at the same time? Or Something else?

Comment: @akalanta If you have view pager you need to set `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` on it so that it doesn't destroy its views.

Comment: Hello there, I tried to use what you mentioned above yourTab1Fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tb1_r1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in onCreath() in main class to set the table row visible and set text for textview of fragment tab1 but it gives me a null pointer error. Do you know why? Is it because tab1 has not been loaded yet? The viewpager.setOffScreemPageLimit worked for the other methods except for OnCreate().

Comment: @akalanta yes- view has not been created yet. You can pass your data to fragment and in fragments oncreateview retrieve that data and set